# TypesafeConfig REST or remote configuration service implementation

Tags: scala, configuration, config

I'm trying to integrate a remote configurations REST based service as part of my project's configuration fallbacks.

I've been using [TypesafeConfig](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.typesafe/config/1.3.2) up to now, with a simple file-based approach:

```
lazy val appConf = ConfigFactory.parseResources(Constants.APP_CONF_FILE)
```

but now, I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
lazy val remoteRESTConfigService: Config = ConfigFactory.parseResources("https://example.com/remote_config_api")
lazy val fileConf: Config = ConfigFactory.parseResources(Constants.APP_CONF_FILE)
lazy val appConf: Config = fileConf.withFallback(remoteRESTConfigService)
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?